# Unspecified Error when attempting to set a shape's .Line.Visible property in PowerPoint

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have a bothersome problem, which is affecting one user.

I am unable to replicate the error on my machine. The other developer I'm working with cannot replicate on his machine either.  We are able to isolate the error on a user's machine, though.  I am running Win 7 Enterprise Version 6.1 Build 7600, with MS Office 2010/PowerPoint 2010/etc.

The relevant error occurs for **one user** on the `.Line.Visible = msoFalse`.  The error raises as:

```
Run-time error '-2147467259 (80004005)':
Method 'Visible' of object 'LineFormat' failed
```

Visible is clearly a *property* of the shape's `.Line`.  I can view it in the Locals window:

[image]

I am able to query this property value in the immediate window without an error:

[image]

Entering: `tb.Line.Visible = msoTrue` makes the line visible (as expected)

Entering: `tb.Line.Visible = msoFalse` yields “Automation Error/Unspecified error” with same code:

[image]

Here is some sample code. I have tried dimensioning `tb` as `Shape` but this yields a `Type 13 Mismatch` error. I have also tried setting the property value to `0` instead of `msoFalse` but the error persists.

```
Sub TestCode()
Dim cht as Chart
Dim tb As Object

    Set cht = ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes("Chart 1").Chart
    Set tb = cht.Shapes.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, ptLeft, tBoxTop, ptWidth, ptHeight) 'NOTE: tb.Type = msoTextBox

    tb.Select  '<--- KEEP THIS LINE OTHERWISE TEXTBOX _
               '     ALIGNMENT WILL NOT WORK 

    With tb
        With .TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters
            .Text = "foo"
        End With
        .Fill.Visible = msoFalse
        .Line.Visible = msoFalse
        .TextFrame2.WordWrap = msoFalse
        .TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Bold = True
        .TextFrame2.TextRange.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = msoAlignCenter
        .TextFrame2.AutoSize = msoAutoSizeTextToFitShape
    End With
End Sub
```

This subroutine is wrapped in a master error handler from a form button-click event, so we do not lose data or crash the application, but it does prevent the Add-In from building the chart/graphic in the desired manner.

Since the default `.Line.Visible` *is* `msoFalse` (so I can comment out the offending lines of code) this is not particularly critical, but it does require a code change and redistribution of the PPAM.

I am wondering why this is happening, and whether there is a way to "fix" this that does not involve commenting out the offending lines, or doing an `On Error Resume Next` approach.

**Update** (from comments, to clarify)

This example is one of several such subroutines designed to handle the placement and formatting of textbox callouts, these are all shapes of type `msoTextBox` which are added within the shapes collection of an existing shape, e.g., a Chart shape.

All similar calls to `object.Line.Visible = msoFalse` fail with the same error.

, each will raise the same error on her machine.   Other similar calls, e.g., `.MajorGridlines.format.Line.Visible = msoFalse` does **not** error.

Comment: the point worth mentioning here is that, for me, what's happening is it is throwing "Method 'Visible' of object 'LineFormat' failed" error, but it does remove the line before throwing this error. pretty strange. But in such a scenario, if I put On Error Resume Next for this line and the resume error handing after this line is working fine for me. I am not sure about the reason though.

Comment: @Vikas strange indeed -- it's actually *removing* that line from VBE module??

Comment: @enderland not sure what you mean by "all objects" this is a specific subroutine designed to manipulate `msoTextBox` shapes inserted in a Chart shape.  I will add a few sentences to OP to hopefully clarify this.

Comment: err, I somehow missed you were programmatically creating the object... (doh)

Comment: No worries! @enderland

Comment: sometimes i do get these random errors popping. to fix it i export all forms/modules/class then remove them and save the file. restart ppt and open that file to import everything back, then no more of those random error.

Comment: @patrick7 that's simply not an option on a distributed PPAM.  This file type can't be saved after it has been compiled into an add-in, also unreasonable to expect end users to do this,  also, I don't know if programmatic way to access an add-in's VBProject so I'd have to ex/im about 50 code modules manually.  Hard to do for a user on the other side of the country :)

Comment: @David, not the VBA Code line. Lol. What I meant is, I set the Visible Property to true, it brought the line in the textbox. When I tried .Visible=false, it gave me the error, but the line from Shape was also removed. So if I suppress the error by using on error resume next, my code works just fine.

Comment: I don't think Patrick7 meant for the user to do this; it's something you'd do in your source PPTX file before saving again as PPAM. Since it occurs only on this one user's PC, I'd also check to see what .Build the PPT application reports.  Charts and tables got badly broken in PPT 2007 and have been mostly patched back up moving forward, but there may still be some glitches in older versions that newer versions/updates patch away.

Comment: @SteveRindsberg Odd thing is this user perviously did not have this error. Just started happening about 2 days ago, user has been using the application for several weeks.

Comment: I will add a version# and build# to the error log though and see if there's differences among users.

Comment: In addition to the logging, I'd look at their windows/office update history; see if anything showed up at about the same time as the errors started to occur.  MS pushes out bad updates from time to time, stuff that causes odd problems like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not exactly a satisfactory answer, but I avoid the error simply by commenting out the offending line(s) of code.  Since, when the TextBox is created, this property is already set to `msoFalse`, it is redundant code and can be omitted.